# How to add messagebox correctly in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I faced a syntax error with The method

```
setPositiveButton(String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) : is undefined for the type AlertDialog
```

how to solve it ?

---

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("error msg");
alertDialog.setMessage("You should register before");
alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//dismiss the dialog  
 }
}); 

alertDialog.show();
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead;

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Then, after all the settings, do the `.create();`

And take away that `AlertDialog alertDialog = null;` It has no use.

Next time, try to look up if the method is actually in the class you're trying to call it on. `alertDialog` was a `AlertDialog`, which does not have this method. This should ring a bell for you to look for which class it is in exactly.

Comment: Try doing the .create() after all the settings

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        this);
alertDialog.setTitle("error msg");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
                alertDialog
                        .setMessage("You should register before");
                alertDialog.show();
```

you should implement DialogInterface.OnClickListene
eg:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener{}
```

then you will get override method OnClick.

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                        //do what ever you want on OK click
            } else if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                        //do what ever you want on Cancel click

            }
        }
```

If you want just an message box use

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                alertDialog.setMessage("You should register before");
                alertDialog.setButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // here you can add functions
                            }
                        });
                // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                alertDialog.show();
```